# Problem of extrusion with mirror

Tags: modeling, mesh, vertices, extrude

This is my mesh (the cube) and the goal is to extrude the upper part

[image]

The idea is to get **THIS FINAL RESULTS BELOW**:

[image]

In order to achieve this goal, I used ,as always ALT + S, but the result was this one:

[image]

My question is: **<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>s</kbd> works perfectly with all the mesh i used before: why in this case, with a mirror, i get that distorsion? Is there a way to fix it?**

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to switch "even thickness ON", after command starts...

eg: after pressing <kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>...

[image]

then pressing <kbd>S</kbd> or <kbd>ALT</kbd>, thus getting:

[image]

which it seems to be what you wish to obtain...

Comment: Or, to put it simpler, initiate with Alt+S, then press S again to turn on "even thickness". The "interactive" variant would be Alt+S, then press and hold Alt.